# Why @Html.Action when is inside in a block, it does not show its Html?

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I spend two hours to realized that if I put a Action inside of a block, it does not show the partial view.

```
<div>
    @if (ViewBag.Tab == "summary")
    {
        Html.Action("Summary");
    }
    else { ... } 
</div>
```

But if I do the following it works, but if not what I want:

```
<div>
    @if (ViewBag.Tab == "summary")
    {   <div>
        Html.Action("Summary");
        </div>
    }
    else { ... } 
</div>
```

Is there a way to show the partial view using the first option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples would work properly. `Html.Action` returns an `MvcHtmlString`. You need to prefix it with an `@`:

```
@if (ViewBag.Tab == "summary")
{
    @Html.Action("Summary"); // prefix with @ works fine.
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't have idea about that.. sorry if the question was stupid! But thank you so much!